# Swift and Open Sound Control (OSC) communication

Tags: javascript, swift, osc, opensoundcontrol

we've had a simple requirement of triggering commands via the following 3 commands:

```
1.) `/hog/playback/go/0/1'
2.) `/hog/playback/go/0/2'
3.) `/hog/playback/go/0/3'
```

i've no idea on how OSC communicates but considering its somewhat a UDP/TCP connection transferring bytedata?

used: https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftOSC SwiftOSC library
and simply parsed the messages as following:

```
let message = OSCMessage(address, self.message.text!)
client.send(message)
let message = OSCMessage(address, "/hog/playback/go/0")
client.send(message)
```

further, i could also move to javascript or someother solution that just allows sending data to OSC on an ip/port where the server is.

Answer (score 1):

The address is the `/hog/playback/go/0/1` and not the text when using SwiftOSC